# Deactivate doublepresses on some keys without using a specific keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Everytime I want to use a backtick or other special symbols I need to press the key twice which results in it writing `` instead of just one of them.

I already found some solutions online that requires changing to a US keyboard in Windows, however, i'm not using a english keyboard but rather a swiss one, is there a way to deactivate these "doublepress keys" without changing the keyboard in Windows 10?

Comment: You shouldn't have to press a keyboard button twice to print a character, sounds like the problem is with the physical hardware, and not with software.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a intended feature because you can combine them like ¨ + i = ï, however I never need any of these so I wouldn't mind getting rid of it

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard?

Comment: I only have this one keyboard and don't want to buy another one. Although I did have some laptops and they had the same thing (just never bothered asking).

Comment: Remove the international keyboard.

Comment: How do I do that? The only tutorials I find require to switch to the US keyboard and I don't want to do that because of said reasons. I only installed "German (Switzerland)", no other language.